Any way to make a checkbox system to write out a list?
I am trying to set up a system on Google Sheets, where checking a checkbox will write out a list, for example:
Clicking on a checkbox AB will add "AB" to 1 single cell. Clicking on CD, will add "CD" on the same cell, after AB, unless AB was not checked, in that case CD will be first.

Ideally, it would look like this.

But I don't know what's the most efficient way to do this.
I tried using a =IF formulas, which worked for marking a single project, but doing more than 1 results in an #ERROR

Use FILTER() and TEXTJOIN() function.

=JOIN(", ", FILTER(A7:A, C7:C))

I wrote a Named Function called stringbuilder for this purpose. It take 3 parameters, joinchar, rangestr and rangeckbox.
=TEXTJOIN(joinchar, true, MAP(rangestr, rangeckbox, LAMBDA(string, checked, if(checked,string,""))))

Here is an example to call the named function:
=STRINGBUILDER(", ",A2:A6,B2:B6)

Here is a screenshot of it in use:

I have started a library of useful named functions, feel free to make a copy for yourself
Named Function Library


You may try:
=join(", ",filter(A7:A14,C7:C14))

